# Unable to Resolve Class org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I updated my environment via GVM so that I can test drive the latest Groovy/Grails. In the GGTS IDE I started a new Grails project with version 2.4.4. I created a basic domain class and controller and went to visit the page. The first thing that I noticed the default Grails UI was missing, no HTML/CSS. I figured it was a plugin that needed to be included, I wasn't worried about that. I figured I should create the connection to MySQL and add my usual custom dialect, this is where I have been stuck for the last several hours. I Googled and searched but could not find the answer or someone else facing the same problem. The only thing that I can think of is that the new version of Grails comes super light and you have to manually add plugins and features that you want???

Anyhow, this is the code for the dialect:

```
import java.sql.Types
import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

class MySQLCustomDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect { 

    MySQLCustomDialect() { 
        registerColumnType(Types.BIT, 'boolean') 
    }

}
```

I switched to Hibernate 3 also getting the same error. Not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: What's the "default Grails UI"? It looks like you have more significant problems than just org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect. Does this compile from the commandline?

Comment: Try right-clicking on the node in the left tree and running Grails Tools | Refresh Dependencies

Comment: That's the one thing that I did not do was refresh dependencies, that seems to solved the issue. I thought deleting the target and target-eclipse did the same thing as refresh dependencies by forcing grails to rebuild everything.

Comment: Regarding the UI, when I launch the app in the browser it's not the default Grails look and feel, it's basically a skinless page with no style at all. I am just scaffolding at the moment, I did not generate the files, but I know in the past when working with Grails it would still have the default ui look and feel. Everything is compiling fine, the only error i'm trying to resolve now is ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException

Comment: It really bothered me and I wanted to find out what happened, so I started from scratch and decided to generate a plugin and a new project. I must have generated a plugin at first and that's why the UI was not available.